# Сборка всех CSS файлов в один через Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, webpack

Начала изучать Webpack и первым делом решила переписать свою gulp-сборку.
Одна из базовых задач в ней - рекурсивно идти по всем папкам проекта, собирая все CSS-файлы в один.

Сборку явно указанных css-файлов я сделала, но импортировать каждый css-файл (прописывая имя) неудобно, хочется просто написать что-то вроде import '/**/*.css' и все.

Прошу рассказать, как правильно настроить webpack для решения такой задачи.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356239/webpack-how-to-put-all-css-files-into-one-css-file первая ссылка на которую наткнулся в гугле. В чем проблема сперва гуглить?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader